# How to prevent ConvertFrom-Json from collapsing nested arrays if there's 1 element

Tags: json, powershell, member-access-enumeration

Consider these two JSON files:

```json
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "action",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "region",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "count_",
          "type": "long"
        },
        {
          "name": "min_timestamp",
          "type": "datetime"
        },
        {
          "name": "max_timestamp",
          "type": "datetime"
        }
      ],
      "name": "PrimaryResult",
      "rows": [
        [
          "ChangePassword",
          "CN",
          1,
          "2022-07-19T11:51:52.8430729Z",
          "2022-07-19T11:51:52.8430729Z"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

```json
{
  "tables": [
    {
      "columns": [
        {
          "name": "action",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "region",
          "type": "string"
        },
        {
          "name": "count_",
          "type": "long"
        },
        {
          "name": "min_timestamp",
          "type": "datetime"
        },
        {
          "name": "max_timestamp",
          "type": "datetime"
        }
      ],
      "name": "PrimaryResult",
      "rows": [
        [
          "ChangePassword",
          "CN",
          1,
          "2022-07-19T11:51:52.8430729Z",
          "2022-07-19T11:51:52.8430729Z"
        ],
        [
          "Register",
          "CN",
          1,
          "2022-07-19T11:51:52.8430729Z",
          "2022-07-19T11:51:52.8430729Z"
        ]
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

They have the exact same schema and are almost the same. The difference is that first file has 1 row in the `rows` property, the second file has 2 rows in the `rows` property.

---

I use `ConvertFrom-Json` to load the files into PowerShell. When I start accessing `.tables.rows[0]`, I expect that it will return the first row.

However, in the first file that has only 1 row, it actually returns the first column of the first row.

```
(gc file1.json | ConvertFrom-Json).tables.rows[0]
```

Outputs:

```
ChangePassword
```

---

If there are more than 1 row as in the second file, then the `.tables.rows[0]` behaves as expected.

```
(gc file2.json | ConvertFrom-Json).tables.rows[0]
```

Outputs:

```
ChangePassword
CN
1
2022-07-19T11:51:52.8430729Z
2022-07-19T11:51:52.8430729Z
```

---

How can I reliably process these JSON files in PowerShell regardless of if they have 1 row or multiple rows in them?

btw. These are actually JSON files produced by `az cli` as results from Azure Application Insights queries.

Comment: Try with `@( , (gc file1.json | ConvertFrom-Json).tables.rows ))[0]` can't test from my phone but I think you're looking to prevent enumeration

Comment: Try `(gc file1.json | ConvertFrom-Json).tables[0].rows[0]`

Comment: @nimizen Also works, nicest solution yet. I don't understand why though... I'd accept that as the answer if it wasn't a comment.

Comment: or dont index through the array? `$json.tables.rows`, I don't see it as unexpected behavior.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala But what if I need to get the first row? Or what if I need to iterate through all rows and process the data somehow? If I use `$json.tables.rows`, it behaves differently each time. For example, what if I want to just count rows (i.e. `.tables.rows.count`)? If there's one row, it returns the number of columns (`5`) instead of the number of rows (`1`). If there are two rows, it returns correctly `2`. Hope it helps explaining my problem, but I guess one has to try it to see the issue.

Comment: I still don't see the issue. There are 2 arrays, so it will give you a count of the 2 arrays. How would it know what to unroll and what not to unroll? `@(1,(1,2)).Count` gives you 2, while `@(1,(1,2)).ForEach{$_}.Count` gives you 3.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Please try it with the JSON files posted in the question. Try the 1st file and run: `(gc file1.json | ConvertFrom-Json).tables.rows.count`. You'll get `5` instead of `1` (there's one row there).

Regarding the unrolling, I do not wish it to unroll anything and respect the original structure of the JSON file.

Comment: Correct, because it get's unrolled and the content is what's counted.

Comment: PowerShell consumes the outer array during enumeration when there is only 1 nested array, this is why pretending the comma operator `,` before the expression works. It wraps the single array in a new array. Hard to explain from phone but can post an answer later if nobody does

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Thanks, I think I get this now. But I fail to understand the answer from @nimizen. Why is `$json.tables.rows[0]` different to `$json.tables[0].rows[0]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr**

You need to avoid [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) if you want to access collection-valued properties as-is, which in your case means the following, as [nimizen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/431646/nimizen) demonstrated in a comment:

```bash
# Note the [0] after .tables
# (-Raw was added for efficiency)
(gc -Raw file1.json | ConvertFrom-Json).tables[0].rows[0]
```

Because your `tables` property is itself an array, accessing just `.tables` results in member-access enumeration (even though the array happens to have just *one* element).
Using index `[0]` to target that one element explicitly allows access to its (one and only) `.rows` property without the latter's value being subject to *implicit enumeration*, as explained in the next section.

---

You're seeing a **surprising aspect of PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) feature**:

The values obtained from the members of a collection's elements are emitted as if they were sent to the *pipeline*, *one by one*, which has the following implications:

- As happens by default in the pipeline, any such value is *enumerated* if it happens to be collection-valued, i.e. its *elements* are emitted, one by one.
- On *accessing* the resulting output, if there's only *one* output object (whether or not that happens to be a collection itself), it is captured as-is; if there are *two or more*, they are implicitly collected in a regular PowerShell array (of type `[object[]]`).

The **upshot for enumerated member values that happen to contain *collections*** is:

- The input collections *themselves* are always lost, because only their *elements* are output.
- If there are *multiple* collection-valued member values, you'll end up with a *single, flat array*, invariably of type `[object[]]`, that is the *concatenation* of the elements of all collections involved.
- If there is only *one* collection-valued member value, and that value happens to be a *single*-element collection, you'll end up with that single element *as-is* (only with *multiple* elements would you end up with an `[object[]]` array).

This surprising behavior is the subject of [GitHub issue #6802](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6802), though note that the behavior is unlikely to change, so as not to break backward compatibility.

---

A **simplified example** to demonstrate what happened in your case:

Note: JSON is incidental to the problem, so I'm using a `[pscustomobject]` instance below.

```bash
# Construct a single-element array that has a [pscustomobject] element.
# whose .prop property contains a single-element array whose only
# element is another array, typed [int[]].
$array = , [pscustomobject] @{ prop = , [int[]] (1, 2) }

# Use member-access enumeration to access the .prop member value
# of all elements in the array (here, there's only one), and get
# the first element.
$array.prop[0] # !! -> scalar 1, i.e. the first elem. of the *nested* array,
               # !! because member-access enumeration *enumerated* the 
               # !! single-element outer array.

# Without member-access enumeration, the value of .prop is accessed as-is,
# as a nested array:
$array[0].prop[0] # -> [int[]] (1, 2), as expected.
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains it well. I'm familiar with the pipeline and this behavior regarding collection flattening, but I was not aware that member-access enumeration exists and that it basically turns it into a pipeline... It makes sense now.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @TomPažourek. I wish it worked differently, but changing the behavior now would be a serious breaking change.

Answer (score 1):

don't know how to stop powershell behaving that way,
but got it "reliable" by

```
$test=Get-Item ".\file.json" | get-content | convertfrom-json
if($test.tables.rows[0].count -gt 1 ){
    $result = $test.tables.rows[0][0] 
}else{
    $result = $test.tables.rows[0]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work fine for getting the first row.

Any idea how to work with this if I want to iterate over all of the rows, and not just get the first one?

I guess I kind of need to do the opposite, instead of always getting a single row, make it always get an array of arrays. But I'm failing at that... I'm trying `[object[][]]$test.tables.rows`, but it's still a plain array, not array of arrays...