# ConvertFrom-Json unpacks arrays with 1 item and behaves oddly with empty object

Tags: powershell, powershell-7

I am trying to figure out how to stop ConvertFrom-Json from unpacking array types if they have one or zero items.

I have read these related posts:
[ConvertTo-JSON an array with a single item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662967/convertto-json-an-array-with-a-single-item)
[How to prevent ConvertFrom-Json from collapsing nested arrays if there's 1 element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73037455/how-to-prevent-convertfrom-json-from-collapsing-nested-arrays-if-theres-1-eleme)

After reading these, I don't think I am experiencing the member access enumeration because I am not using the access operator.

I attempted to use ConvertFrom-Json without the use of pipelining but that didn't fix the issue as it did for someone using ConvertTo-Json

Here is a simple example with output:

```
$x = '[{"a": 1, "b": 2}]'
$y = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $x

$a = '[]'
$b = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $a

Write-Host $y -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host $y.GetType() -ForegroundColor Green

Write-Host $b -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host $b.GetType() -ForegroundColor Green
```

```
@{a=1; b=2} # first object in array, not array
System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject # treats as object instead of array
# nothing was printed here because b is null
InvalidOperation: C:\Users\username\Test.ps1:11:1 # error from trying to print the type of b
Line |
  11 |  Write-Host $b.GetType() -ForegroundColor Green
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

The kind of output I expected was the `GetType()` calls to return `System.Object[]`

Additional Context:

I am using the github cli to get lists of PRs for different repos and aggregate some data for some internal workflows. Obviously it is possible for a repo to have 0, 1 or more PRs and I am hoping to avoid any special logic for the 0 or 1 case, as an empty array or array with one item can follow the same code path as an array with many items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing implies that you're using [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) rather than *Windows PowerShell*.

While your command happens to work in *Windows PowerShell*, it relies on behavior that contravenes the usual pipeline behavior, i.e. *enumerating* arrays - see the (now closed) [GitHub issue #3424](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3424) for background information.

It is for this reason that in PowerShell 7+ [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) now enumerates the elements of a parsed-from-JSON array *by default*, and requires *opt-in* in order to request that a such an array be output *as a single object*, using the `-NoEnumerate` switch:

```
$x = '[{"a": 1, "b": 2}]'

# Note the -NoEnumerate switch (v7+)
$y = ConvertFrom-Json -NoEnumerate -InputObject $x

$y.GetType().Name # -> 'Object[]', proving that the array was preserved.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, this worked exactly as expected.

Comment: @BraidenCutforth, I Just aswered a similar question: [Powershell ConvertFrom-Json unexpectedly produces a string instead of object array from single item array containing a string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76987056/1701026), where I actually missed the point that Windows PowerShell acts differently.